# как отключить редирект на главную страницу

Tags: wordpress

подскажите как отключить редирект на главную страницу, если в ссылке прописать что-то типа example.com/blablabla перенаправляет на главную, 404 ошибки нету, мне нужно что бы открывалась ссылкa типа example.com/page2.php, на сайте cms wordpress, в админку по ссылке example.com/wp-admin заходит,
на хосте все проверил там нету редиректов

.htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: а по какому пути лежит ваш файл 'page2.php'?

Comment: в корне, там же где и index.php

Comment: у меня идентичный .htaccess и если положить файл в корень, то он откроется. За это, как раз, и отвечают два условия RewriteCond - перенаправление на index.php произойдёт только в случае, если путь не является файлом или папкой. Получается, ваш файл не воспринимается как файл. Возможно, проблема в правах доступа на файл, может у вас нет прав на чтение файла

Comment: в wordpress в корне лежит файл license.txt, если вы его не удалили. Проверьте, открывается ли он?

Comment: я пробовал разные файлы, и даже подпапки, все равно перенаправляет, да license.txt есть и открывается

Comment: можете проверить, какие права выставляются файлам, которые вы добавляете? Это должно быть 3 или 4 цифры, что-то, типа "0644"

Comment: все файлы: adfrw(0640), у index.php такое же число

Comment: На всякий случай, уточню, вы кладёте в корень сайта файл 'page2.php' и пробуете его открыть по урлу 'http:// example.com/page2.php', но вас кидает на главную страницу, как если бы вы просто открыли http:// example.com ?

Comment: да все верно, но ссылка остается такой же http:// example.com/page2.php и рисует главную страницу, даже если файла нету и просто попробовать открыть http:// example.com/page22222222222222.php все равно отрисует главную страницу, даже не перенаправляет, а сразу рендерит главную страницу

Comment: на всякий случай - содержимое файла page2.php просто рандомное сожержимое? (просто текст?)

Comment: да просто разметка html, я и пустой файл пробовал и просто текст, все равно тоже самое

Comment: сдаюсь )
то, что нет 404 ошибки - странно, у меня есть при неверной ссылке, может, это связано с проблемой. Посоветовал бы развернуть сайт на другом хосте\локально. Если открывается license.txt, то пока все ещё подозреваю права доступа или есть ещё, вроде, такое понятие, как владелец файла (по-моему так называется)

Comment: сейчас увидел в консоли браузера 404 (Not Found) не видит страницу, то есть получается какой бы файл я не добавил браузер его не видит